# "go to look for somebody in the place" vs "go to the place to look for somebody"

Tags: sentence-construction, to-infinitive, infinitive-phrases

Given sentence:

> Off they went to look for the astrologer  in the forest.

Question:

> Where did they go to look for the astrologer?

Possible answers:

> 1. They went to the forest to look for the astrologer.
> 2. They went to look for the astrologer in the forest.

I am so confused with the verb in this sentence is
**went** or **went to look for**.

Comment: Are you trying to choose which answer fits the question best? Then it is answer 2, because the key part of the question is "where", and the key part of the answer is "in the forest". This key part is positioned at the end of the sentence.

Comment: My answer would be: _**In the forest**._ (No, that's not a complete sentence – but that's still how I'd answer the question.) Your longer sentences sound contrived, particularly as answers to the question.

Comment: J. R., the answer sentences are not contrived. They are formal.

Answer (score 1):

A simple question once again made into a conundrum.

The given statement is deliberately misleading. It should have been written as; *Off they went to the forest to look for the astrologer*.

---

**Question**

> **Where did they go** to look for the astrologer?

---

**Given sentence.**

If you go somewhere it obviously a location. There is only one physical location mentioned in the given sentence.

> Off they went to look for the astrologer in ***the forest***.

---

**Answer**

> **They went to the forest** to look for the astrologer.

The fact that the given answer gives a  reason why they went to this location is not relevant.

---

The alternative, incorrect, answer **does not tell where they went** to, just that they looked for the astrologer who is in the forest. You may assume they went to the forest but It does not say that they did. Possibly they went to the Ranger's hut to see if they knew where he was, we do not know. It does not tell us.
The fact that **the phrase "the astrologer in the forest"** is mentioned in the "*given sentence*" and the "*alternative answer*" **is a "red herring".**

Answer (score 0):

As a learner, I think there are two key issues:

The first is that in English you can use "to+infinitive" after many verbs. In fact, many verbs **license** "to+infinitive". One of these verbs is **go** (went, and gone):

> They went to do something

The second is that the preposition "to" is usually used after verb "go" to refer to the place that the subject goes:

> They went to the forest.

Therefore, the pattern used in your examples is similar; you can add more information by using adverbs and prepositional phrases:

They went to somewhere **to do** something

They wen **to look for** something in somewhere (Note look for is a two-word verb)

They went **to buy** some food from the Bob's grocery store.

In all of these sentences the main verb is "**go**"

Comment: Which is suitable more  from the OP?

Comment: What about at: They went to look for him AT school, at home. The in/at is important. in the closet/at the station. Very often a source of confusion for learners.

Comment: @Lambie OP asked about the verb in those answers. Didn't they?

Comment: @learner Oh, sorry. I didn't think you want to select one of them. I would go with the first answer because the question asks about the place and the first answer is more direct in this sense.

Answer (score 0):

You have two verbs in this sentence: go and look. One answer has them adjacent, "went to look", and the other has them separate.

Both of your possible answers are equally correct.